# Evaluating $|A\cup B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A$ and $B$ are the subsets of the same universal set
>
> $$|A' \cap B| = 2$$
>
> $$|B'-A| = 4$$
>
> $$|A-B|' = 11$$
>
> $$|B|' = 13$$
>
> Evaluate $|A\cup B|$

There are too many equations so I could not solve this problem using Venn Diagram. Perhaps I have to go more conceptually. Could you assist me?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean $|(\cdot)|'$? Should it not be $|(\cdot)'|$?

Comment: So $A'$ is the complement of $A$?

Comment: "There are too many equations so I could not solve this problem using Venn Diagram" Actually I would highly recommend using a Venn diagram (that's how I would work this out)

Comment: There are exactly two sets involved, so the Venn Diagram in question will be very simple.

Comment: @Stockfish Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $|A-B|'$ and $|B|'$ do not make any sense, because $|X|$ turns a set $X$ into a number. And you can't take the complement of a number, only of a set.

So $|A-B|'$ should be $|(A-B)'|$ or $|A-B'|$ and $|B|'$ should be $|B'|$.

If you think it's hard to construct a Venn diagram, you just do it with little steps.
For example with $(A - B)'$: first you draw the Venn diagrams of $A$ and $B$, then $A - B$ and then $(A - B)'$.

## $|A' \cap B| = 2$

[image]

## $|B' - A| = 4$

[image]

## $|(A - B)'| = 11$ or $|A - B'| = 11$

[image]
[image]

## $|B'| = 13$

[image]

## $|A \cup B| =\ ?$

[image]

Now you do the math!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following two relations for any two sets $M,N$:

- $M \setminus N = M \cap N'$
- $|M| = |M \cap N| + |M \cap N'|$

Assuming you mean $|()'|$ instead of $|()|'$  and setting $U$ to be the universe here you may proceed as follows:

- $|B' \setminus A| = \color{blue}{|B' \cap A'| = 4}$
- $|A'| =|A' \cap B| +  |A' \cap B'| = 2 + 4 = 6$
- $11 =|(A\setminus B)'| =|(A \cap B')'| = |A' \cup B| =  |A'| + |B \cap A| = 6 + |B \cap A| \Rightarrow |B \cap A | = 5$
- $|B| = |B \cap A |  + |B \cap A' | = 5 + 2 = 7$
- $13 = |B'| = |U| - |B| = |U| - 7 \Rightarrow \color{blue}{|U| = 20}$

Finally
$$\boxed{|A \cup B|} = \color{blue}{|U|} - \color{blue}{|B' \cap A'|} = 20 - 4 \boxed{= 16}$$

Comment: The box and blue highlights are very nice and illustrative. Today I learned.